# GetResponse Objective-C Integration

Tags: objective-c, ios7, getresponse

I need to create an iOS app that needs to use a form created with `GetResponse`.

Does anyone know if the integration between the two systems is possible and if there is any documentation or example about it?

Thanks in advance.

Massimo

Answer (score 0):

Please, try start there: http://apidocs.getresponse.com/en
If you need some further directions, just post question here :)